# How do I document union type variables?

Tags: coding-standards

My module has a class with a union type member variable

```
/**
 * This is a PHPv8 union type variable that can be a string OR null.
 *
 * @var string|null
 */
protected string|null $myVar;
```

However, when I run the code sniffer with `phpcs --standard=Drupal,DrupalPractice ...`, I'm always getting an error like

```
FILE: MyDummyClass.php
----------------------
FOUND 1 ERROR
----------------------
  46 | ERROR   | Missing member variable doc comment
----------------------
```

In this special case, I was able to use the nullable shorthand as a workaround

```
/**
 * This is a PHPv8 union type variable that can be a string OR null.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected ?string $myVar;
```

But this workaround only works for one single nullable union. As soon as I use the union operator `|` in the `@var` line

```
/**
 * This is a PHPv8 union type variable that can be a string OR int OR null.
 *
 * @var string|int
 */
protected ?string|int $myVar;
```

I'm getting the phpcs error message again.

So how do I properly document union type variables, following Drupal practices?

Comment: That looks correct to me, is this a case of the linter rules not being updated?

Comment: I think so, [according to PHP8](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/union-types) Doc comments aren't needed/necessary anymore.

Comment: The code works as expected, it is just the phpcs "error" about the doc block. If I remove remove the either the complete docblock or only the `@var` line, the code sniffer throws an error when using Drupal standards.

Comment: I believe all methods are able to be NULL, and therefore don't have that included in the docblock.

Comment: OK, makes sense for `null`. But there is still the question how to get `string|int` (or any other combination using the pipe character) through the code sniffer.

Comment: Can you confirm the version of Coder in use?

Comment: Should be the lastest: `PHP_CodeSniffer version 3.7.1 (stable)`, composer outdated doesn't list any available updates

Comment: I mean the Coder version, the thing which contains the rulesets.

Comment: "But there is still the question how to get string|int (or any other combination using the pipe character) through the code sniffer" I'd argue this is a bad practice. Properties should either be empty (null) or contain the value of the type you are storing. If there are multiple types, I'd say you need to reconsider your architecture.

Comment: Currently using v8.3.13 for coder. I see an update for 8.3.16, but version conflicts with dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer:^1.0 (which is set by drupal itself) prevents me from updating.

Comment: Union types support was added in 8.3.14 https://www.drupal.org/project/coder/releases/8.3.14

Comment: But that could be because Core is still supporting PHP 7.

Comment: OK, so I'll just sit it out :-) I needed a solution for null, the rest was more kind of an academic question.